# How to fetch the value of a field in a document in Firestore database

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code that fetches my data from my BJ document in my Firestore Database.

```
docRef.getDocument(as: City.self) { result in
    // The Result type encapsulates deserialization errors or
    // successful deserialization, and can be handled as follows:
    //
    //      Result
    //        /\
    //   Error  City
    switch result {
    case .success(let city):
        // A `City` value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
        print("City: \(city)")
    case .failure(let error):
        // A `City` value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
        print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
    }
}
```

With this class :

```
public struct City: Codable {

    let name: String
    let state: String?
    let country: String?
    let isCapital: Bool?
    let population: Int64?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case state
        case country
        case isCapital = "capital"
        case population
    }

}
```

I need to get the value of the "street" field that's in the BJ document. I'm really stuck. Does anyone have a way to get the value of the fields in a firestore database ?
I can't find nothing in the documentation. Like how do you know the values of the fields in documents?

I already tried with custom classes and i can't get the values of some fields, I just get everything at once.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I found a better solution, I just need to use `let firstNameValue = data["Name"] as? String`